# Auto URL Update in Magento

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting, magento-1.9

My Original URL from Admin side is:- https://www.demo_detail.com.au/demo/index.php/admin/system_account/index/key/0652b9f2f23d1fe363efeb14879d34c3/

But My Problem is whenever I click any Admin side tab at that time Magento automatically rewrite the URL like:-
https://www.demo_detail.com.au/demo/demo/index.php/admin/system_account/index/key/0652b9f2f23d1fe363efeb14879d34c3/

so I want to Remove extra demo from my URL.

Comment: Have you checked your core_config table?? Your base url might be  https://www.demo_detail.com.au/demo

Comment: yes checked its ok @Bilal

Comment: I think there is a problem in .htaccess but i couldn't find that. @bilal

Comment: if you recently transfer your site to sub domain then clear cache and log tables too.

Comment: but when I clear cache from admin side it throws to 404 because there are an extra demo in URL and that's why I can't do reindex and clear cache or anything @urfusion

Comment: you can clear cache by deleting cache files from `/var/cache` folder and for re-indexing the data edit url by console and remove extra demo

Comment: can you tell me how to edit URL by the console in ubuntu @unfusion

Comment: what the scenario is before 2 days not a single demo comes in URL after that I do some changes in .htaccess file and now 2 demo comes :)

Comment: can i show you .htaccess file @urfusion

Comment: please update your question with your htaccess